# CSS link and change property when hover

Tags: html, css, hover

How can I change another class's property when one's hovering.

If I say I have A and B class, A has hover event, If I want to change inside of B when A hover, how can I do?

```
A:hover {}

B{ color:#FFF; }

A:hover + B{ color:#000;  } didnt work
```

**Actually CSS**

```
.has_child is inside of .navi

.navi > ul > li:hover 
+ .navi > ul > li > .has_child:after {
    color: #09F;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <nav class="navi ">
    <ul>
      <li style="height:8px; width:8px; padding:0px; margin:0px;">&nbsp;
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="MM_no_child">General Config</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="MM_has_child">Menu</a>
        <ul>
          <li style="height:8px; width:8px; padding:0px; margin:0px;">&nbsp;
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="MM_no_child">English</a>
          </li>
          <li>&nbsp;
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="MM_no_child">User Level</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="MM_no_child">User</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="MM_no_child">Tag</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="MM_no_child">Log</a>
      </li>
      <li>&nbsp;
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Thank you very much for your advice.

==============

**Update**

Seem like + operator will nor work if have > before.

A:hover + B{ color:#000;  }  will work fine.

A:hover + C > B{ color:#000;  } will not work.

Comment: What is your HTML structure?

Comment: its HTML5, am I answered correct?

Comment: No. How does the structure look? What elements do you have?

Comment: Please add your HTML code (for example `<div></div>`)...

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.

[image]

You should check your selectors. What browser are you using?

Comment: mine is like  .navi > ul > li:hover +.navi > ul > li > .MM_has_child:after { }, didnt work

Comment: try using `+ li > .has-child:after` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`.A` must be inside `.B`

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        something
    </div>
</div>
```

then in your stylesheet:

```
.A:hover .B { some css code }
```